# Request gives error "connect closed due to timeout"

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using quickblox in my app

I am trying to retrieve a dialog with certain user IDs

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setObject:@"occupants_ids" forKey:@[@([[[DataManager sharedCenter]chat_user]ID]), @(self.opponent.ID)]];
            [QBChat dialogsWithExtendedRequest:dict delegate:self];
```

and the result is this:

```
2014-08-09 13:47:02.843 App New[8752:8e0b] Performing async request: 

GET https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.xml

headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.9.1";
    "Qb-Token" = verylongtokencensored;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}

parameters:{
        (
        1434093,
        1367118
    ) = "occupants_ids";
}
2014-08-09 13:47:02.848 App New[8752:8e0b] Request finished, response:

headers:{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 09 Aug 2014 10:47:02 GMT";
    Etag = "\"0c1aa29ff51b425a9be969d4fbb487a1\"";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2014-08-09 12:47:02 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
    Status = "201 Created";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = 2330d50ea8c08851cafd30ea4c1a1c6b;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.022278";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}

body:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session>
  <_id>53e5fc26535c12a2f700aa3c</_id>
  <application-id type="integer">10910</application-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2014-08-09T10:47:02Z</created-at>
  <device-id type="integer">0</device-id>
  <nonce type="integer">399</nonce>
  <token>verylongtokencensored</token>
  <ts type="integer">1407581207</ts>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2014-08-09T10:47:02Z</updated-at>
  <user-id type="integer">1434093</user-id>
  <id type="integer">54616</id>
</session>
error:


2014-08-09 13:47:02.852 App New[8752:60b] received result:QBDialogsPagedResult,success:0,status:0
2014-08-09 13:47:02.852 App New[8752:8e0b] Request finished, response:

headers:(null)

body:

error:

2014-08-09 13:47:02.853 App New[8752:60b] Errors=(
    "Connection closed due to timeout. Please check your internet connection."
)
```

How do i fix this error ?

Other requests sent to the api, which is not /chat/Dialog.xml they work fine, no connection timeout error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to use filter **all**:

```
  [dict setObject:@"33,55" forKey:@"occupants_ids[all]"];
```

this will found all the dialogs where occupants_ids = "33,55"

you also can use filter **in**:

```
[dict setObject:@"33" forKey:@"occupants_ids[in]"];
```

this will return all the dialogs where **occupants_ids** contains 33

Answer (score 0):

my bad my request had setObject forKey turned around, it should have been

```
        [dict setObject:@[@([[[DataManager sharedCenter]chat_user]ID]), @(self.opponent.ID)] forKey:@"occupants_ids" ];
```